# Very odd problem with browsers caching my page even when instructed not to

Tags: django, caching, web-deployment, cloudflare

I have a Django app served on EC2, and Cloudflare sits in front of the app to cache the static content (JS and CSS files; images are hosted separately on S3 and served via Cloudfront again with Cloudflare on top).

Every time I deploy new CSS, the hash in the filename of my CSS file changes, e.g. `my_stylesheet.12345678.css`.

Occasionally, after a release that involved a CSS change, I get some users emailing me that the website renders as "just text". Investigation led to find that the page in their browser has HTML that points to a previous release of the CSS file, e.g. `my_stylesheet.11111111.css`, which doesn't exist on my webserver anymore.

Since my website is very dynamic (it's a social network, so most pages will change at every request due to new posts, new comments, new likes, etc), to address this issue I have removed all client-side caching: I now send this header with pages like the main page:

`cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0`.

I achieve this with Django's `@never_cache` decorator.

These are my Cloudflare page rules:

[image: Cloudflare page rules]

And these are the request/response header for the main page when I request it:

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 111.111.111.111:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 63b9a4726dbe0e26-MXP
cf-request-id: 0947e51b7f00000e2661a28000000001
content-encoding: br
content-language: en
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 06 Apr 2021 08:28:23 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Tue, 06 Apr 2021 08:28:23 GMT
nel: {"max_age":604800,"report_to":"cf-nel"}
report-to: {"max_age":604800,"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=YSpdY1LGNVOgbemDSBUL5DCg%2FDAX9NY3iGwLfpGvdQDQW9bxtzHIsNUxWFzei98JPs3IM2B4M%2FfepaN2CmIRH90HeUwOlYvCyNz%2Btd3iWavI"}],"group":"cf-nel"}
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: AWSALB=JcZVQeHr1BkaITzKti5bhIEeq9J9qZTufpjPTIvZukaeWLIEjlsOn75fFZXCIyMWN1F/NIYX2c7PsddmxAGNCSKp5EJxiZ59AKVTyOgVAfH89pqUPfX++uC3OUfF; Expires=Tue, 13 Apr 2021 08:28:22 GMT; Path=/
set-cookie: AWSALBCORS=JcZVQeHr1BkaITzKti5bhIEeq9J9qZTufpjPTIvZukaeWLIEjlsOn75fFZXCIyMWN1F/NIYX2c7PsddmxAGNCSKp5EJxiZ59AKVTyOgVAfH89pqUPfX++uC3OUfF; Expires=Tue, 13 Apr 2021 08:28:22 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
set-cookie: csrftoken=oUjzFDSxELNFfgtfNjqxIEkufxlyPaVaFXqsu7wK4jbK7xN1Z2ZQr5z0oDo9AYKO; expires=Tue, 05-Apr-2022 08:28:23 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
set-cookie: sessionid=".eJyFWE1vG0cM_SuBz_Vg-DVfp8K596S7sJJWsRpZTrVS2iLIfy9Har2zq4ILGL6sOOSQ75GP8-NpfzgPl_X1dO673Xr_fl5f3r8dtmvwOfqn8oQe4dnTM-IKUpFUmJ1-YoxPv1i21NrKylMhX5hcDBgi2LY884uFU0F2zAGQbNvQ2vIKoXgpnF2MEdOCbWptaQW5QCwcnAacAtq2ubElWKHGDEWCo5SIxLAF73H97X24PBWSnIPlJbVeMK6ANS0FvEOUwHZWQ_rwErI3vcjMixQtPaFTF0DZ9JJ4VndNgqYxOS27eDvCFKZ-1VbTCOQoQAWUaQvTulesxkLsMIeMyc6__y8zQQ8wvcxQDb5gKj66CIEz2xHi7HZKh1CIXK4IWcgMfdQuIZtVnngJK6guCgaHlIO3axdiawsVXZyLeAdad7QwrLZhylmk4nPlDoJkqtw5dd_X28tf-rPr0J-twxI2hMBkus3TkNUtQaHkJIUgVtkrIaa2vt61wg1JYW7DLYcxwljJdDxsv9bvX_vT_b-eHfXuMQKHKOyV2vF504W4Zc6y2cnGd7WFnvs_rr16mRnFKDFFLQk8x-2eCYlS7pOk3S2wB3frmtT1aTjs9AwOrCeA__U3byOf5AP5KDw7t9tu-2FYH_vv_VEPrdZmTih-5CSy0mj3e3f68r4-6v9r96XXIw6Xhd4xohzMPhjHXhYDWTfEj0IFSNnm5-g9avjr7np5vad10201ITWz3XA5v28OJ1c_us_X4fL-9vLvV-twkYfR4rWl1rGU0G5tlGW8rEd76DZtwmzxMNYqhWglEMaGwhr8CpUiUBtKIkS7bQWMrS1XWxUBys7EzAstL8PIMJqW47UbXvVg2FASvyHZxbDdeYxd2Kad0qon2vq4Y9hsYxdtnZJz40bMKTEmN9-Q1HJlfz0eT91bBfnn1-587IdPL-duN7x2fy50uhYXeeVjEb5LDu0xXm2H69tbd_57vT8cL_15eCo_fppR8jjLLGZo-5PmPgYEahkbDpkAZJmqIJ0gKh48OT0lBXuCxDxG7o2mr3eMj5BElaYuYea4MOtDa3uLUCc4RycMSRZ02ux29xnng9PuHtnbttz6vWna-6BKOXCyqFCRN8uqXlaqLSnLeUlbPlQEQxF0GDyRpWnVttVU5G_glILggETY0hJVU03zrLZMVf8rZUkW1M6IzJRMTiKMyASzu4emu4v5yzhOoYgyG9Drod-ee_34RKHb61ymDjDC3u8XkNNg255CY9tL3uQvxZnium9JpFsSJVhQy6GZdfS_euLjorzBxEk6LVsOu009uOnFd71hiwxqoRBWOvh0rdJ1QiIx2bShCYykUl0UvuxAFWdaEjePfvlGGx0oJvR1LKRmLFiTNEwbihI73hY_r7cDbZcLgrtZyUwZ40OzopiUoHGZQbTaekaYAUjDptoKM2jB7daAMp3s_nZrFp1bwZuLqNrOVUHt3YWi89Gr6rVtwxQP6lcTrq2fKPu4EDNMx4ZOJsWSEkYCxYUVHf3DyMFcY1amBbMFK5Z8o7WM8ale8gPa9c-DE9Al1mYKpgdbHTBYH1yEiMdNo9-tv_Xnt8MwHN5Pw6Kwz-LTDOGiha5RoUpXc6hX7jcLht3KR9yCLcQwNQg3fllV7nQZVoTrQqvrevIpLmyH2U9t749B5PXW4mNY0K5TVaeCub5hqdonf1d11mY5Hbp1o6Xbo5uA7rQLj1_N8DDHTJZphPWdRW8HjlMMCxIKc5N_8zEip8c8QBUfVEFpP5fkPLO95QHEcVX9C49QuREQCyJ4Jo-gPsqIMi4KJbNSyTc7lJiyuNngVKDavbGR2kZu617W8MVegUfxAWy-pkizaVqdqt59yo761oPFi_ZSZYefP1FUqdCuR4f-0wt6MPJb28448qL5GjCqwCrDTYKMrVi1h_2wNP4SzDNDaLxb7YimpIPbG6XmDXRvUSFkUbvuPE25rchDKxWyOW5AHqSLLp9ETvevFGwFyQ2ks703N4u8RZMaTxM5__wHd3-R6w:1lTh4R:vHTnt7OdEA38hHpwyLYi3Ir0Vyg"; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2021 08:28:23 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=15552000; Path=/
vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cookie
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
:authority: www.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: (redacted)
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
```

The issue is not specific to a browser, because I've had people report it about Chrome, people reporting about Firefox, people reporting about Safari.

One user had the same issue across all his browsers in his network, across multiple devices.

What could be causing this? How can I fix it?

Please let me know if you need more information to help me.

Thank you!

Comment: You've checked your HTTP-level caching settings thoroughly, so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. In particular, your use of hashes in the CSS filenames indicates that you use some kind of build or bundling system that's not native to Django. How does that system communicate the updated filenames to Django's template rendering system? You might want to investigate in that area.

Comment: Hi @DJRamones, thanks for your comment. I believe the problem does not lie in the bundling system (`django-pipeline`) because every single time a user reported this problem, I told them to clear their browser's cache and it fixed the problem every time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `django-pipeline`, but just an idea: could it be that your users are chancing upon a split-second window when the build system is still running but the app already has to serve them a page, so the app just serves the latest valid static file URL it knows? (This is only a good theory if this is how the build system behaves in such a scenario, and if you are employing CI/CD in your deployments.) But that at the same time, the file is already in the process of being deleted from wherever it is that is the main serving location of your static assets.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I did a little bit of digging and I think I've identified the app you're working on. If I'm right (it's open-sourced on GitHub?), then it seems you're using both `pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler` and Ruby `compass` in the static files pipeline. Which means there are several engines working to build the CSS during deployment, and that in turn means a higher probability of unexpected behavior when the build is still in progress. But I'm really just guessing, though I've encountered a similar issue in a Node/Sails/Grunt app, and unfinished builds were to blame.

Comment: Hi @DJRamones, thank you very much for looking :) Yes, my app is on GitHub so I guess you found the right one. Regarding CI/CD: I employ stickiness at the load balancer, so this is not happening during a deploy, if a server replies with index.html but the request for the CSS file falls upon a different instance. The issue also happening when all my instances are running the same image anyway. I think your second theory is also wrong: the SASS is not compiled in real time, but at build time, so at that point the name of the final CSS bundle is fixed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on details of path to your end users?  I'm pretty sure there some intermediary that is caching it and not invalidating as it should be.

Comment: @tukan 1. browser makes the request for mywebsite.com; 2. Cloudflare DNS resolves to AWS ALB, which resolves to EC2 instance; 3. EC2 instance serves page with HTML/JS/CSS, the request for HTML has the no-cache header; 4. Because there are CSS files, the browser asks for them; 4. Cloudflare DNS resolves the request and serves either the Cloudflare-cached CSS file or picks it up direcly from the EC2 instance (no S3, no Cloudfront).

Comment: Thank you, there is no CDN in the path?

Comment: @tukan, no, not in the path of CSS/JS files. I use the CDN only to serve images (it's an image hosting website / social network).

Comment: I see, then I admit I'm out of ideas.  Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

Changes to caching are not retroactive, meaning that if your users visited your website before you made the changes to the cache headers then the old cache control header would still be in effect.

In order to fix this, hope that your initial cache headers were setup to expire or refresh soon, otherwise users will need to manually clear their cache.

This also applies to proxies outside of your control that may have possibly cached your web page as well. Proxies inside your control should be purgeable.

Since you are using hashes in the filenames for resources you can leave the old files in place when you release a new version. This way your website won't break for users who still have old versions cached which refer to old versions of resources.

In order to have the latest version of the website load for users when they refresh the page, we use the following cache control for all index/html pages:

```
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
```

Comment: Thanks. My initial settings were using eTags, which Django does by default. I'm already surprised that this was an issue, to begin with, as I'd assume Django would serve a different eTag when the content of the HTML changed. Yesterday I did a release that updated the CSS but so far no reports, so fingers crossed!